# Count <td> Elements in xhtml <table> with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, adobe-indesign

i've an XSLT 2.0 which transforms an xhtml Table into an InDesign XML Table. This XSLT counts the **maximum number** of `<td>` Elements within every row `<tr>` Line 7 in the template below  (`max(for $td in //tr return count($td/td))`).

```
<xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:element name="id_table">
        <xsl:attribute name="aid:trows">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(child::*/tr)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="aid:tcols">
            <xsl:value-of select="max(for $td in //tr return count($td/td))"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I've no idea how to realize this with XSLT 1.0 - any ideas would greatly appreciated! Sadly there is only a 1.0 Processor in the Workflow Pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:attribute name="aid:tcols">
  <xsl:for-each select="//tr">
    <xsl:sort select="count(td)" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(td)"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:attribute>
```

should do.

Comment: If you've several tables in the document you need to adapt line 2: `<xsl:for-each select=".//tr"`